# Determine $n$, $m$ for which $\Bbb Q_n \subseteq \Bbb Q_m$.

Tags: galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Determine $n$, $m$ for which $\Bbb Q_n \subseteq  \Bbb Q_m$. How to derive this. I am having no clue. I guess $n|m$. But what is the proof?

Comment: I assume that $\Bbb{Q}_n$ stands for $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ with $\zeta_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$. Hint: If $n\mid m$ can you write $\zeta_n$ in terms of $\zeta_m$? Warning: that notation for the cyclotomic field is not in universal use. The reason is that when $n$ is a prime number $p$, the notation $\Bbb{Q}_p$ more or less universaly refers to the $p$-adic completion of the rationals. Undoubtedly the author of your textbook never needs that, so, as always, context makes the intended meanind clear.

Comment: But, you know the drill on the site. Preferrably show some work. Such as the relevant cases with $n,m\in\{2,3,4,6\}$. You may see an anomaly (which is a mild hint that you haven't found the universal truth yet).

Comment: Yes but what about converse that if $\Bbb Q_n \subseteq \Bbb Q_m$ then is $n|m$?

Comment: What about $n=6, m=3$?

Comment: I have tried a lot with it but having no clue about condition

Comment: If there is a primitive $m$th root of unity AND a primitive $n$th root of unity in a field, then there will be an $\ell$th primitive root of unity where
$\ell=l.c.m.(m,n)$. Combine this with  what you know about the degrees of the extensions $\Bbb{Q}_\ell/\Bbb{Q}$. And, in case the penny didn't drop, all the extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ contain a 2nd primitive root of unity. Basically you are invited to play a bit with the Euler's totient function.

Comment: Sir your writing is not clear. Will you please edit it?

Comment: So what exactly the condition will be? Yes $\Bbb Q_l$ will be in $\Bbb Q_m$. But $\Bbb Q_n \subseteq \Bbb Q_m$ imply what?? Which is iff condition also.

Comment: Actually $\Bbb Q_m = \Bbb Q_l$. But what the condition will be?

Comment: If $n=6$ and $m=3$. Then it is not true i.e not a subset.

Comment: And I don't know anything about Euler's totient function.

Comment: If L.H.S is true then $\Bbb Q_m\Bbb Q_n=\Bbb Q_m= \Bbb Q_l$. So $l=m$ hence $n|m$. Am I right? I think this the arguement.

Comment: Because $\zeta_{2n}=-\zeta_n^{k+1}$ whenever $n=2k+1$ is an odd integer, we always have $\Bbb{Q}_{2k+1}=\Bbb{Q}_{4k+2}$. I don't know how to do this without Euler totient function $\phi(n)$. Its role is kinda central here because
$$[\Bbb{Q}_n:\Bbb{Q}]=\phi(n).$$

Comment: Oh ok sorry I know $\phi (n)$ as Euler's phi function. Sorry.. I am giving a solution please check whether it is true or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim $\Bbb Q_n \subseteq \Bbb Q_m$ iff $\phi (m)=\phi (l)$ where $l=l.c.m(m,n)$

$\Leftarrow$

we know $\Bbb Q_n\Bbb Q_m= \Bbb Q_l$. Now $\Bbb Q_m \subseteq \Bbb Q_l$ and $\phi (m)=\phi (l) \Rightarrow [\Bbb Q_l:\Bbb Q]= [\Bbb Q_m:\Bbb Q] \Rightarrow \Bbb Q_l=\Bbb Q_m \Rightarrow \Bbb Q_n \subseteq \Bbb Q_m$

$\Rightarrow$

If $\Bbb Q_n \subseteq \Bbb Q_m \Rightarrow \Bbb Q_n\Bbb Q_m= \Bbb Q_m=\Bbb Q_l \Rightarrow \phi (m)=\phi (l)$

Comment: So far so good. You know that $m\mid \ell$ and $\phi(m)=\phi(\ell)$. Can you use the formula for $\phi$ to prove that together these imply $\ell\mid l.c.m.(2,m)$?

Comment: Yes from there we can conclude that $n=d$ or $2d$ where $d= gcd(n,m)$.